# jQuery Filter children which has a particular attribute

Tags: jquery

I have some `li` elements among them some of the `li` has an attribute `data-brandId` and some of them don't have this attribute. I have the parent `ul` from which I am filtering it as:

```
var selectedLis = new Array();
$('ul').children('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr(attribute) != null) {
        selectedLis.push($(this));
    }
});
```

Is there any better way to achieve this; like by using `filter` etc?

### Update:

I am getting `TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined`

The rendered HTML is:

```
<li data-entityid="WF/008/DAM" class="dropdownli filterItem">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" data-entityid="WF/008/DAM" value="WF/008/DAM/014" name="damBrand">
    <label>E&amp;W Portfolio</label>
</li>
```

This is giving me the error:

```
var lis = $('ul[name=damBrandMenu]').children('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('entityId').length;
});
```

Also say I don't have the data-entityId in the `li`, instead I have this attribute in the input[type="checkbox"] which is the child of li, as you can see in the HTML. Then what will be the way for filtering? Is it:

```
var lis = $('ul[name=damBrandMenu]').children('li').filter(function(){
    return $('> input[type="checkbox"]', this).data('entityid').length;
});
```

I have also tried: `$(this).attr('data-entityId').length;` and `$('> input[type="checkbox"]', this).attr('data-entityId').length;`, but they are also not working. I am having same error; `TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var selectedLis = $('ul').children('li[data-brandId]');
```

or with a filter:

```
var selectedLis = $('ul').children('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('brandId');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am having an error, `TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined`. I have updated my question.

Comment: @TapasBose - try it without the `length`, or  `return $(this).data('brandId') != 'undefined';` !

Comment: it is not giving any error, but returning wrong result. There are 11 `li` among them 9 has this attribute. the code that you have shown is returning all of them. But `$('ul[name=damBrandMenu]').children('li').filter(function(){
 return $('> input[type="checkbox"]', this).attr('data-entityId') !== undefined;
});` is giving 9, the correct result.

Comment: Yes, if you're trying to check the data attribute on the checbox, you'll have to target the checkbox inside the filter. I was pretty darn sure that jQuery returned an empty string if the data attribute did'nt exist, but if it returns undefined, you will of course have to check for that. It's hard to post code that matches exactly when the initial question did'nt mention any checkboxes etc.

Comment: `$('ul[name=damBrandMenu]').children('li').filter(function(){ return $(this).attr('data-entityId') !== undefined; })` this also works without `checkbox`. I have solved the issue. I will post later.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('ul > li').filter(function() {
    return this.dataset.brandId
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var attribute = 'data-brandId';
var selectedLis = $('ul > li['+attribute+']');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var selectedLis = $('ul li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('brandId').length;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am having an error, `TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined`. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JQuery attribute filters for this as,

```
var selectedLis = $("li[data-brandId]");
```